# Explanation of Merge Sorting with PHP

Tags: php, sorting, recursion, merge

Merge function working correctly.I have 2 queries in merge sort
1) I am not able to get why "merge" function calls third time(print execute) here  when count==1 condition mets two times for both left and right together.
2) If I comment return $x then printing $x shows blank array third time otherwise $x show sorted array in third time why?

```
$arr= array(4,2,7,5);
$count= count($arr);
//Merge Sort

$result= merging($arr);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); exit;
function merging($arr)
{
    $count= count($arr);
    if($count==1){ return $arr; }   

    $mid= ceil($count/2);
    $left= array_slice($arr,0,$mid);
    $right= array_slice($arr,$mid);

    $left= merging($left);
    $right= merging($right);
    echo "execute";
    $x=  merge($left,$right);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($x); //exit;
    //return $x;
} 


function merge($left,$right)
{  
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($left);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($right);
    $l=0; $r=0; $temp=[];
    while($l<count($left) && $r<count($right))
    {
        if($left[$l]> $right[$r])
        {
            $temp[]= $right[$r];
            $r++; 
        }else{
            $temp[]= $left[$l];
            $l++;
        }
    }
    while($l < count($left))
    {
        $temp[]= $left[$l];
            $l++;
    }

    while($r < count($right))
    {
        $temp[]= $right[$r];
            $r++;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Comment: `merging()` is an odd choice for the method name because it is "splitting" or "halfing".  I am still trying to understand what your strange recursive function is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mickmackusa okay, could you please help me why third time merge function execute.

Comment: @NigelRen  First time merge run count==1 fulfill left=4,right=2 then second time  count==1 fulfills and left=7,right=5 after why merge function execute when count==1 not fulfilling.

Comment: @AnilTomar I've keep staring at your script thinking -- there's got to be a better way to do whatever you are trying to do.  Here is some diagnostics: https://3v4l.org/ePo7H

Comment: After looking a bit more, it looks something like a bubble sort.  It splits the list and then sorts each side, this in turn splits the list until there is only 1 item in the list.  The results are then merged into a sorted list back up the chain.  So each call is sorting each successively smaller list of items.

Comment: @mickmackusa why the third time "execute" word echo when count==1 condition not satisfied. How it's getting possible third time merge($left,$right)calls?

Comment: I think you are not understanding the behavior of recursion.  The initial iteration doesn't "go away" once the recursive call is made; it is just delayed until all of the subsequent recursive processing is done.  I don't know how to explain this to you -- which is why I didn't answer.  See how in my demo, there is a `array (
  0 => 4,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 7,
  3 => 5,
)` at the start and at the end?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for your help but still didn't why initial iteration doesn't go away as according to logic count==1 mets two times. If possible any simple iteration function or reference link for this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'll be able to explain myself to your satisfaction, but I did indulge in having a play with this code and found some other similar snippets from around the web:

- [Writing merge sort in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9401019/2943403)
- http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Merge_sort#PHP

As for your code, by commenting out the return value, the higher levels of recursion were denied the updated data coming from the subsequent/lower levels of recursion.  In other words, `null` was passed back to `merging()` instead of array-type data -- which of course is non-iterable/non-countable.

I also found your code to be too much for my brain to follow, so I made some changes to reduce the code bloat and single-use variables.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/REQAa))

```
function mergeSort($array) {
    echo "array = " . json_encode($array) . "\n";
    $count = count($array);
    if ($count == 1) {
        return $array;
    }
    return merge(
        mergeSort(array_splice($array, 0, $count / 2)),
        mergeSort($array)  // use the leftovers
    );
}

function merge($half1, $half2) {
    do {
        $temp[] = $half1[0] < $half2[0] ? array_shift($half1) : array_shift($half2);
    } while(isset($half1[0], $half2[0]));
    return array_merge($temp, $half1, $half2);  // gather any potential remaining elements
}

$input = [4, 2, 7, 5, 3];
$input = mergeSort($input);
var_export($input);
```

Output:

```
array = [4,2,7,5,3]
array = [4,2]
array = [4]
array = [2]
array = [7,5,3]
array = [7]
array = [5,3]
array = [5]
array = [3]
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 7,
)
```

or with your input, the output is:

```
array = [4,2,7,5]
array = [4,2]
array = [4]
array = [2]
array = [7,5]
array = [7]
array = [5]
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 7,
)
```