# Is it possible to stably sort an array in O(n log n) with constant auxilliary space?

Tags: sorting, stable-sort

Given an array of *n* elements, is there a sorting algorithm that

1. sorts in at most *O(n log n)* time (and optionally, *O(n)* time in the best case)
2. is stable
3. takes *O(1)* auxilliary space

All sorting algorithms I found satisfy only two of these criteria:

- bubble sort satisfies 2 and 3
- merge sort satisfies 1 and 2
- heap sort satisfies 1 and 3

Is there an algorithm that satisfies all three criteria?

Comment: But isn't it possible to implement merge sort in a way such that it sorts in place? Even for arrays?

Comment: That is not possible due to the recursion. When the recursion works its way down a recursion tree, the height of the recursion tree will be at most log2(n). The algorithm will require at most that amount of space to keep track of the branches taken in the recursion.

Comment: @Kent Archiving O(1) extra space (assuming a transdichotomous machine model) is indeed possible; see heap sort and bubble sort.

Comment: @FUZxxl My response was to the question about merge sort above my response. I should have made that clear. I did not account for transdichotomous machine models, I assumed just a standard machine model. If you had a CPU with infinite cores, the answer would also be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stable, efficient sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113025/stable-efficient-sort)

Comment: @Kent btw, you do not need recursion in Mergesort; you can track how deep you are currently recursing and calculate the bounds of the array you're merging from there.

Comment: @Fuzxxl, good point. The hardest part will be the implementation of an algorithm that merges two sorted arrays in place. It is indeed possible, but such an algorithm is not straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/optimal-sort-algorithm-in-number-of-swaps/7250#7250)

> There exists a stable in-place sorting algorithm with O(n log n)
> comparisons and O(n) moves.
>
> See: Gianni Franceschini: Sorting Stably, in Place, with O(n log n)
> Comparisons and O(n) Moves. Theory Comput. Syst. 40(4): 327-353 (2007)
> [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00224-006-1311-1)

Comment: Can you give some more explanation? Per FAQ, a mere link to a ressource is not enough for an answer. Also, the algorithm is paywalled and unaccessible for me.

Comment: Here is a free source describing a technique which tries to remove the big constant overhead often coupled with stable sorting with O(1) additional space: http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/35/6/643.full.pdf